# Find closest ocurrence of "." in VIM

Tags: vim

In VIM how do you find the next dot "." using the command `f`? I tried `f.` and it doesn't work.

> [image]

Comment: Note that the manual page says **to the right** (of the cursor on the same line).

Comment: @Jens yeap thanks, it can go to the left if you do capital f `F`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f.` works for me as long as its on the same line. If you want to search across lines you'll have to search with `/` using `/\.`.

Comment: And with `?\.` you can search backwards, with `n` to the next ocurrence in the same direction, with `N` to the next ocurrence in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that f is only for the current line, and / is for searching forward. / uses REs, so you must escape ., thus the key sequence `/\.<ENTER>` does the trick.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe `f\.`

You may need to escape . since it is a special character which will match any character.

Comment: No, the argument to `f` is a literal character, not a regexp.  See the other answers.